# Is it true that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \notin \Theta(g(n))$ necessarily implies $f(n) \in o(g(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Is it true that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \notin \Theta(g(n))$ necessarily implies $f(n) \in o(g(n))$?

Despite knowing the definitions I'm unsure on how to prove or disprove this. I've tried finding a counter example, but it seems impossible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write out the precise definitions for each of the above?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a case where $f(n)$ alternates between $g(n)$ and something much smaller.